# Is there a way of having an undefined string passed to an Image in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I currently have this bit of code :

```
  const renderImage = (imageUrl: string) => {
    if (imageUrl)
      return (<Image style={styles.image} source={require(imageUrl)} />);
    return (<View></View>)
  }
```

and the error I am getting is : "Invalid call at line 28: require(imageUrl)".  I would have thought that the "if(imageUrl)" would have sorted that out.

I have tried but the image is not being rendered:

```
  const renderImage = (imageUrl: string) => {
    if (imageUrl)
      return (<Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: imageUrl }} />);
    return (<View></View>)
  }
```

EDIT:  The imageUrl will be null while loading data which is what is causing the error.

Comment: Could you share example link from `imageUrl `?

Comment: At app load the url is undefined.  When the adata has loaded it is a normal https url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you import `Image` from `react native` and add styles for width and height:

```
<Image style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}  source={{uri : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWR5C.jpg?s=256&g=1"}} />;
```

**Example**

```
import React from "react";
import { Image, ImageRequireSource, ImageURISource, View } from "react-native";


const imageURI = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWR5C.jpg?s=256&g=1";

const assetImage = require("./assets/images/icon.png");

const RenderURIImage = ({ imageURI }: { imageURI: ImageURISource["uri"] }) => {
  return (
    <Image source={{ uri: imageURI }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
  );
};

const RenderAssetImage = ({ image }: { image: ImageRequireSource }) => {
  return <Image source={image} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <RenderURIImage imageURI={imageURI} />

      <RenderAssetImage image={assetImage} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: when image doesn't have width or height it doesn't show error, just doesn't show image

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are passing size to image because image need size to render otherwise it will never render. You can try something like this.

```
<Image style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}  source={{uri : imgUrl}} />;
```

And also you can add default image.

```
<Image style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}  source={{uri : imgUrl || defaultImg }} />;
```

So you can confirm it what's going on. I hope it will work.